# Core Location didEnterRegion didn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

works only if the UIView corresponding to class that implement CLLocationManagerDelegate is active.

If I changed the view it wont trigger didEnterRegion. Anyone can help me?

My code look like this

```
- (void)enableRegionMonitoring {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myMonLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.766699790955, 76.650101525879);
    CLRegion *myRegion = [[CLRegion alloc]
                         initCircularRegionWithCenter:myMonLocation
                                               radius:100
                                           identifier:@"MyLoc"];
    //NSLog(@"reg=%@",myRegion); 
    // Start monitoring for our CLRegion using best accuracy
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:myRegion
                              desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region");

    NSDate *nowx=[NSDate date];


    UILocalNotification *localNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if (!localNotification)
        return;
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"qw" forKey:@"mykey"];
    [localNotification setUserInfo:data];

    [localNotification setFireDate:nowx];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSMutableString *message=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    message = @"Local Not Triggered By didEnterRegion";
    [localNotification setAlertBody:[nowx description]];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: What are you looking exactly? because if you want to fire delegate event it must require to set delegate for it.

Comment: already set delegate 
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
I want to trigger a notification when I enter a region.

Comment: please help me..I'm really stuck on it

Comment: that means didEnterRegion note fire at least ones ?

Comment: yes. If the View Corresponding to class that implement CLLocationManagerDelegate is active, then it fires all the time.
but keeping that view active all the time is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code I guess you are using ARC, depending on your controller/view hierarchy your view and controller might get deallocated when you switch to a different view, when this happens the locationManager will be deallocated too.

Just to move the whole CLLocationManager code to your AppDelegate and let the AppDelegate be the CLLocationManager delegate. Where you are now calling "enableRegionMonitoring" you would call it on your AppDelegate instead. This will stay active even if the ViewController isn't visible anymore.